# How to stop the generation of strace.out files

Tags: linux, jboss, jboss7.x, redhat

I started the JBoss instance using the following command:

`strace -o strace.out -ff ./startMethodServer.sh`

Now i want to stop the generation of these strace.out files

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue about JBoss, but would advice to remove

```
-o strace.out
```

from invocation, since the the usual behaviour of many cli tools is to specify an output file with `-o outputfile.`

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to stop the server and restart it without `strace`. The `strace` command has nothing to do with JBoss AS. It's part of the OS therefore it must be controlled by the OS.

Comment: If I understood his question directly, then he wants to stop generating .out-files. Did I misread his question?

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
strace -o strace.out -ff ./startMethodServer.sh
```

is running the script `./startMethodServer.sh` using `strace`.  The `strace` program is writing the `strace.out` file, and will continue doing that until `./startMethodServer.sh` exits.  The only way to stop writing those files is to stop the `strace` process (which *will* stop `./startMethodServer.sh`), and restart `./startMethodServer.sh` without involving `strace`:

```
./startMethodServer.sh
```